# Axios get params array is converting to string

Tags: laravel, axios

Axios

```
    var datas=[{"ticket_no": "1","details": "detail1"}];
    instance.get(`somepath`, {
        params: ({
            data:datas,
        }),
        responseType: 'blob',Accept: 'application/pdf',
        }).then((response) => {
            const file = new Blob(
                [response.data], 
                {type: 'application/pdf'});
            const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            //Open the URL on new Window
            window.open(fileURL);

        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        }).finally(() => {
        })
```

PDF.test

```
{{data}}
```

//returns "{ticket_no:1,details:detail1}"
//not an array but a string

Answer (score 0):

var datas=[{"ticket_no": "1","details": "detail1"}];
    instance.get(`somepath`, {
        params: ({
            data:JSON.stringify(datas),
        }),
        responseType: 'blob',Accept: 'application/pdf',
        }).then((response) => {
            const file = new Blob(
                [response.data], 
                {type: 'application/pdf'});
            const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            //Open the URL on new Window
            window.open(fileURL);

```
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    }).finally(() => {
    })
```

//Controller

```
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('PDF.pdf_irregularity',['data' => json_decode($request->data)])->setPaper('A5', 'landscape');
    $fileName = 'Irregulairty';
    return $pdf->output();
```